# Create a crisp 200px wide logo in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I've used photoshop for years but am new to illustrator. I want to use this to create a crisp 200x wide logo for web use. I created the logo in illustrator, I then exported it to Photoshop and resized it to how I wanted. I'm assuming this is where the quality loss is.

Is there a way to maintain a high DPI in illustrator but set the size 200px wide?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you're hitting the problem is "...exported it to Photoshop." Don't do that.

One of the great things about working with the Creative Suite applications is the way that they can work together, and this is a typical case where working the "old" way (export to a format that the other program understands, then import) is actually counter-productive.

Save your Illustrator file in its native format, then either drag it into your Photoshop banner document or use File > Place.

In either case, the Illustrator file becomes a Vector Smart Object, which you can scale as much as you like. Pixels are rendered on the fly by Photoshop each time you change the size.

As a side note: most of us grew up in the world of individual applications with proprietary file formats and fragmented workflows. Getting past that mindset and starting to think of the different applications as active collaborators, rather than talented but socially-inept loners, is essential if you want to utilize the full power of any them.

Comment: Thanks, so I've done this and what Farray recommended below, but the text is still not perfectly crisp, I'm using Coolvetica font, and even in illustrator, it's actually not as crisp at a smaller size - could it just be the font?

Comment: It apparently lacks hinting information. Even in InDesign it looks crappy below about 24 pt. If you need small text to render well on a screen, it's best to pick one that has been drawn with very low resolution in mind and therefore also has decent hinting. Tahoma, Verdana and Myriad Web are examples of fonts drawn with pixel displays in mind, but there are plenty of others. Times and Arial have hinting information to compensate for screen resolution display.

Comment: It can be worth recreating the text component of your logo in Photoshop for the cleanest results.

Comment: note also, that when not using a smart object, "import, then resize" is a double whammy regarding potential loss of quality. Determine the size first, then import using that exact size. You are going to need to work ont he original image so it works well at the size desired, even if it is vector. After all: when you finally output the banner, even the smart object will need to be rasterized for use on a web page.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator will maintain your art in a resolution-independent way.  If you want to work with a specific size (ie., 200px) you may want to set your artboard to 200pts wide so you know what you're working with.

As far as exporting the file for web use, just use Save-For-Web and set the size to 200px wide and you'll have your file.